# Can a superconductor have a Fermi surface in its superconducting state?

Tags: superconductivity

In the superconducting state, there are Cooper pairs instead of free electrons, so there is no Fermi surface. Is this always true, especially when there are charge density waves? Is it possible that there are still some remaining free electrons at the Fermi surface below $T_c$?

Comment: Yes, in $p$- or $d$-wave superconductors the gap has nodes in the Brillouin zone. Compare [Wikipedia on unconventional superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconventional_superconductor). Of course, this does not imply the quasi-particles there behave exactly like free electrons.